# FOSRestBundle: routes and annotations for parameters

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm able to get GET parameters with `@QueryParam()` annotation, but it looks like it works for Query String data only: `/user?id=123`.

I'd prefer to have it like `/user/123` instead. For this, I might use `@Get("/user/{id}")` annotation, but I don't see it has additional metadata which `@QueryParam()` has:

```
name="id", requirements="\d+", default="1", description="User id"
```

If I use both of the annotations, I get an error:

```
ParamFetcher parameter conflicts with a path parameter 'id' for route 'getone'
```

My conflicting docblock:

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a Users entity.
 *
 * @Rest\View
 * @Rest\Get("/user/{id}")
 * @Rest\QueryParam(name="id", requirements="\d+", default="1", description="User id")
 * @ApiDoc(section="Partner Users")
 * @param int $id
 * @return array
 */
```

PS I need to have an id in the path (`/user/123`), not in query, and I also need to use `@QueryParam()` as it's read by NelmioApiDocBundle. How may I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

FOSRestBundle's `@Get` annotation extends FOSRestBundle's `@Route` which in turn extends SensioFrameworkExtraBundle's `@Route`.

Have a look at the [code](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Controller/Annotations/Get.php#L19) and see the documentation chapter [@Route and @Method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#frameworkextra-annotations-routing-activation).

The `requirements` and `defaults` attributes expect an array.

```
/**
  * @Rest\View
  * @Rest\Get("/user/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
  * @ApiDoc(
  *  description="Returns a User Object",
  *  parameters={
  *      {"name"="id", "dataType"="integer", "required"=true, "description"="User Id"}
  *  }
  * )
  */
 public function getAction($id)
 {
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: nifr, thanks for your help! The only thing doesn't look nice is that single parameter is described twice, in `@Get` and `@ApiDoc`.

Comment: If you drop the `parameters` section from the `@ApiDoc` section and add `@param integer $id Description of id here` below it that seems to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you want a description for requirements just do this in your annotation

```
   /**
  * @Rest\View
  * @Rest\Get("/user/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
  * @ApiDoc(
  *  description="Returns a User Object",
  *  requirements={
  *      {"name"="id", "dataType"="integer", "required"=true, "description"="User Id"}
  *  }
  * )
  */
```